# Can a Platform Event target an individual Salesforce user?

Tags: salesforcedx, integration

I want to send a notification from an external system to notify an INDIVIDUAL Salesforce user that the user is required to take action e.g. A Purchase Order requires your approval. The INDIVIDUAL Salesforce user will vary (e.g. depending on who entered a Purchase order). Ideally, as soon as the PO is entered in the external system I want a pop up message to appear on the Approver's screen in Salesforce notifying them that an order is awaiting their approval.  Can a Platform Event target an individual user?  Or is there a more suitable method to deliver such a notification in Salesforce?

Answer (score 0):

No platform event cannot target an individual user. For this you will have to go for `Generic Events` which can accept user id and it notifies to only those users.

[Generic Events](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_streaming.meta/api_streaming/generate_event_using_rest.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a FeedItem with an [@mention](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/quickreference_post_comment_or_feed_item_with_mention.htm) to notify a user. This will appear as a notification in the UI and their mobile device, if they're logged in. This is probably the ideal way to make this sort of notification, and requires no extra code like a Platform Event would need.